# Nested Resources with Mongoid and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid

Is it possible to nest Users inside another resource (i.e. Accounts) using Mongoid and Devise? For example:

```
# routes.rb

resources :accounts
  resources :users
end

devise_for :users
```

If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working?

```
# routes.rb

resources :accounts
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

First created - higher priority. Verbose paths may change, it will become `new_accounts_sessions_path` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense if you would use such nesting for registrations. In this case do:

```
resources :accounts
  resources :users
end

devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations
```

Also, depending on your Accounts functions, I would play with skipping other controllers to achieve better safety and remove unused paths.